# PHP Programming Syntactic Error

Tags: php

I am new to programming and I am in need of some help. I am getting the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\wamp64\www\project\topic.php on line 99. I did previous research on this but the thing is I am actually following a tutorial on building a simple forum so I am kind of lost here. Can you please assist me in identifying this error.

```
<?php
echo '<tr class = "topic-post"> 

<td class = "user-post"> '. $row ['Username']. '<br/>'.
 ('dmY H: i', strtotime ($row ['Post_date'])). '</ Td> 

<td class = "post-content"> '. htmlentities (stripslashes ($row 
['Post_content'])). '</ Td> 
</ Tr> ';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the call to the `date()` function.

```
<?php
echo '<tr class = "topic-post"> 

<td class = "user-post"> '. $row ['Username']. '<br/>'.
 date('dmY H: i', strtotime ($row ['Post_date'])). '</ Td> 

<td class = "post-content"> '. htmlentities (stripslashes ($row 
['Post_content'])). '</ Td> 
</ Tr> ';
?>
```